# Can electricity be obtained from neutrino radiation, like a solar cell?

Tags: physics, energy, power-generation

Power Technology magazine published a 2019 article *[Neutrino energy: harnessing the power of cosmic radiation](https://www.power-technology.com/features/neutrino-energy-harnessing-the-power-of-cosmic-radiation/).

It describes a new energy technology - making solar panels, but for [neutrinos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino) instead of light.

> In principle, harvesting neutrinos as an energy source is similar to that of a traditional photovoltaic (PV) solar cell. Neutrinos are not captured; instead a portion of their kinetic energy is taken and converted into electricity.
>
> The Neutrino Power Cell is made of layers of silicon and carbon, which are applied to a metallic substrate with surgical precision so that when neutrinos hit them, it results in a resonance. Neutrino Energy discovered how to build such a cell that could convert the optimal level of resonance into resonating frequency on an electrical conductor, and then capture this energy.
>
> [...]
>
> Scientists at Neutrino Energy’s Berlin branch are working on the first technical devices that will be powered by neutrinos.

The technology company has a web-site: [Neutrino Energy](https://neutrino-energy.com/)

This, on its face, seems to be really sketchy.

Can anyone provide a good source to debunk or confirm these claims?

Comment: [Welcome to the new visitors to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) This is going to be a difficult question to answer. It is one thing to have a firm intuition that every part of the claim is complete bunk, but another thing to be able to provide references. (Possibly the best we can hope for is quoting experts in the field rejecting the claims; yes, appeal to authority is a poor argument, but we are unlikely to get better.) Note that we don't accept pseudo-answers in comments here.

Comment: The site seems to be very carefully worded to never actually claim they have a working device but rather lots of fluff to build up excitement. Then they pitch investing via an unregulated "private placement" I would be surprised if this were not a scam. Among other things, only 3% of solar radiation energy  is in the form of neutrinos so even if they did have a device solar panels would still be a better way to harvest energy.